# Convert all canvas with toDataURL()

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm working on a 2d isometric map with HTML5 and canvas.

So, i can have a map with an infinity of tiles, but, I only displayed the tiles around the player and it's my problem.

When i retrieve the image with `toDataURL()`, I just retrieves the small part of the map that I displayed around the player...

I need to retrieve all the canvas, even that is not displayed, is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. `toDataURL` *do* give you the whole canvas but the whole canvas is simply what you see on the screen. Canvas does not know about anything outside this (anything drawn outside the canvas is clipped and forgotten).

If you need to get the complete map you will need to create a big enough canvas and draw the complete map then extract the image. There is no way around (using canvas).